# Unable to fetch image after using Content Import and IMCE module

Tags: views, theming, nodes, media

I am trying to import content for custom content type fields using csv, in content I have images fields as well and using the Content Import Module for CSV import and IMCE module for image upload. After import CSV all content showing but images not showing. The path for images also storing in **file_managed** table 
I have set the permission of the folder still its now showing the images[image]

Also place the image in the /sites/default/files/artist/hero
Please help with this problem?

Comment: Please help for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your folder path should be "`CONTENT-TYPE MACHINE NAME/images`" not artist/hero and set permissions to 777 as per Content Import Module. And also change `File directory` path under that field as "`CONTENT-TYPE MACHINE NAME/images`".